# How to correctly extend a custom Provider in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-change-notifier

I have a parent ChangeNotifier `ParentProvider`, and 2 other providers extend the `ParentProvider`;

`ChildProviderA`, `ChildProviderB`.

I have a route which is called `MyScreen`

```
class MyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    if(ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments != null){
      return ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => ChildProviderA(),
        child: _Screen()
      );
    }
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ChildProviderB(),
      child: _Screen()
    );
  }
}
```

depending on the arguments I want to use a provider, and in either case, I want to call a function called `initData()` in the `ParentProvider` from the `_Screen` widget.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
...
    Provider.of<ParentProvider>(context, listen: false).initData();
...
}
```

This gives me an error

```
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<ParentProvider> above this _Screen Widget
```

If I used `Provider.of<ChildProviderA>(context, listen: false).initData();`

or `Provider.of<ChildProviderB>(context, listen: false).initData();`
It works, but I want in either child Provider used, to be able to call initData.

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Provider.of` looks for provider with exactly given type. It doesn't include child types.

If the child screen needs to access some different data having same format, you can use the same provider in both cases passing it different data through constructor:

```dart
class MyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (condition) {
      return ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => ParentProvider(data1),
        child: _Screen(),
      );
    }
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ParentProvider(data2),
      child: _Screen(),
    );
  }
}
```

If you really have two different ChangeNotifier implementations sharing same interface, you can provide and access them using parent type:

```dart
class MyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (condition) {
      return ChangeNotifierProvider<ParentProvider>(
        create: (context) => ChildProviderA(),
        child: _Screen(),
      );
    }
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ParentProvider>(
      create: (context) => ChildProviderB(),
      child: _Screen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The second example works. It still needed to declare an empty method in the ParentProvider to be able to run it from ChildA, but anyway it saved a lot of code

Comment: To avoid empty methods in parent change notifier, you can make the parent class abstract and declare abstract method

Answer (score 0):

When you define your children providers, use extends.
Also all providers must above the children and in the same route they are listening to. You can try adding extends ParentProvider when defining your children classes. i.e

```
class ChildA  extends ParentProvider {

//here you have access to methods in parent.
you can add a method here that triggers something form the parent.

void childMethod ()=> methodFromParentLikeInitData();

}
```

Comment: this is what I have done, but it doesn't work

Comment: You need to put all of them above your widget.

Comment: do you mean I should use the 3 providers in the route ?

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad `Provider.of` uses `getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType` which doesn't look for subtypes, only exact given type

Comment: @Huthaifa I think I understood your solution, but it will contain a lot of extra functions in both child classes which just points to parent functions